# How to calculate the coverage of a particle in a surface simulated in C?

Tags: c, simulation

I'm trying to simulate in C a square surface that traps two kind of particles. The steps that the simulation follows are:

1. I start with a completely empty surface and then, select an entry of it at random.
2. If the entry is empty, I continue to the step 3). Otherwise, I select another entry
3. I decide to trap particle #1 or particle #2 at random as well. By defining a random number r
4. If r is less or equal to Y, I choose particle #1, otherwise, I choose particle #2
5. Then, I count how many particles of each kind were trapped until the grid was filled completely

But, I need to obtain the coverages of every particle in each iteration, taking into account that the individual coverage is defined by #particle / N, where N is the number of total entries in the matrix and I'm not sure how to proceed.

I need to calculate the coverages in each iteration and then, print that data in a file, called "data". Could you give me some suggestions for that, please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the description but... Isn't the coverage simply `(double)particle1/N` and `(double)particle2/N` at any time?

Comment: Yes, that's the definition of the individual coverage of every particle, but I'm a bit confused about how to store each result in a variable. That is since in my first attempts I obtained coverages bigger than 1 when it needs to be between 0 and 1

Comment: `printf("current coverage %f\n", (double)particle1/N);` should do. Insert it just after `particle1++;`

Comment: Thank you. I have another question: is it also correct to put that print statement after the if...else that counts each type of particle? That is since I need two columns of data so that I can make plots later on

Comment: Sounds fine to me

Comment: You are already tracking count of particle1 and 2 in your code.  All that remains is to create an expression including `N` to get the percent coverage for each particle to print it out.  See explanation below.

Comment: I think you will find that the total follows a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution); maybe you could optimize this a bit if you are finding it's a little slow instead of stepping one at a time, esp. at high-occupancy.

Comment: Yes, I also think I need to optimize my code since I need to add interactions between particles later on. Thanks

Comment: FWIW - Having the code in your post improves it for future viewers.  Without code there would not have been a way to make any suggestions on how to improve it.   Consider rolling back your edit to put the code back in.

Answer (score 2):

> But, I need to obtain the coverages of every particle in each
> iterations, taking into account that the individual coverage is
> defined by #particle / N, where N is the number of total entries in
> the matrix and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Your code already tracks the count of each type of particle generated So if `N` can be defined as:

```
double N = 1.0*sizeof(grid)/sizeof(grid[0][0]);//double avoids integer division
```

Then coverage (in percent of grid size) for either particle type 1 or 2 can simply be:

```
double coverage1 = 0.0; 
double coverage2 = 0.0; 

if(particle1 > 0.0) coverage1 = particle1/N;
if(particle2 > 0.0) coverage2 = particle2/N/;
```

Your original code modified to integrate updated status of coverages:

```
if(r <= Y ){//The particle #1 is chosen  (note modifications)       
    printf("r = %lf is less than Y = %lf. We choose the particle #1\n\n", r, Y);
    grid[j][i] = P1_OCCUPIED;
    particle1++;//count tracked here.
    //output both columns here:
    printf("%0.2lf%%\t%0.2lf%%", 100.0*coverage1,100.0*coverage2);
    availcells--;//necessary?
    fullcells++;//necessary?
}
else{//The particle #2 is chosen
    printf("r = %lf is greater than Y = %lf. We choose the particle #2\n\n", r, Y);
    grid[j][i] = P2_OCCUPIED;
    particle2++;//count tracked here.
    //output both columns here:
    printf("%0.2lf%%\t%0.2lf%%", 100.0*coverage1,100.0*coverage2);        
    availcells--;//necessary?
    fullcells++;//necessary?                
}
```

The output below is modified to take advantage of the few changes

```
printf("The process took %d rounds\n\n", rounds);
printf("#particle1 = %d\n\n", particle1);
printf("#particle2 = %d\n\n", particle2);
printf("#availcells = %d\n\n",(int)(N - (particle1  + particle12))); 
printf("#fullcells = %d\n\n",(particle1  + particle12)); 
printf("coverage particle1: %0.2lf%%\n", 100.0*coverage1);
printf("coverage particle2: %0.2lf%%\n", 100.0*coverage2);
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll take your suggestion about the definition of N and the expression for the available cells. But I need to keep The coverages defined as #particles /N since I need to plot exactly this quantity later on.

Comment: @Auyk:  I'm red-faced.  This `coverage1 = N/particle1;` is a typo.  I had it in my code base here as:  `coverage1 = particle1/N;`. and somehow transcribed it wrongly. Sorry for the confusion.  Will edit my post.

Comment: No worries.  I have another issue and that is when I put the print statements for the coverages after the others, I get 0.000 for them. I moved those prints just below the if-else and it seems it's working. But I'm not sure if that's appropiate

Comment: @Auyk - I do not have the benefit of seeing your updated code, but because `printf` seems to be working to output coverages in a lower location, but not inside the `if/else` blocks, it sounds like the expression used to compute coverage may not be called prior to the `printf()` statements (inside `if/else`).  When in the loop, and needing to output `coverage` values each iteration, the expression computing the updated coverages values needs to be called _prior_ to any printfs outputting those values.